# How to upload Kusto DB schema for tables and functions in Github?

Tags: git, azure-data-explorer, kql

I was having a project in which most part is done in Kusto. I wanted to know what is the best way to upload Kusto table schemas and functions I developed to git so that others can review it. Is creating a text file and copying all the table creation commands, update policies, and function code enough or is there any other elegant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For doing pull request review on git for your functions this is the best way available now. Instead of text file you can keep them in .csl file. Once you kept all the files on csl files you can refer this document. [Azure DevOps Task for Azure Data Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/devops)

This document describes a simple example on the use of the Azure Data Explorer - Pipeline Tools task to deploy your schema changes to your database. You can configure the functions to be deployed upon merging the pull request/scheduled deployment/any other deployment strategies offered by azure Devops.

Comment: what all should we keep in the .csl file? Each command that we used to create the table, functions,  materialized views, retention policies, update policies?? Every command in separate .csl file?

Comment: I think that should be up to your convenience , I would prefer to keep a function, tables it needs, update  policies of those tables, in a single file. If we keep everything on single file on the long run we end up having a very very long file. I would avoid that and keep things very concise in separate files